# R remove column of df inside list of list

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

Hi I have the following structure:

```
list
- list
-- df
--- column
```

data sample

```
participants <- list(list(data.frame("col1", "col2"),data.frame("col1", "col2"),data.frame("col1", "col2")),
         list(data.frame("col1", "col2"),data.frame("col1", "col2"),data.frame("col1", "col2")))
```

I'm trying to delete col1 for each dataframe of each participants. I can do it individually with `participants[[1]][[2]]$col1 <- NULL`
but I'm struggling to automate this with a loop. These ones do not return error but don't seem to do nothing.

```
for( p in participants){
  for (i in p){
    i$col1 <- NULL
  }
}

drop <- c("col1")
for( p in participants){
  for (i in p){
    i[ , !(names(i) %in% drop)]
  }
}
```

Comment: Best to make a minimum data sample (and post it in reproducible form).

Comment: Your example dataframes do not have column named "col1".

Answer (score 1):

We need double loop, something like:

```
lapply(myList, function(i) lapply(i, function(j) j[, !colnames(j) %in% drop ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)


p <- list(list(data.frame("col1", "col2"),data.frame("col1", "col2"),data.frame("col1", "col2")),
         list(data.frame("col1", "col2"),data.frame("col1", "col2"),data.frame("col1", "col2")))

map_depth(p, 2, ~select(.x, -X.col1.))
```